# using SFTP in JSCH to upload files,I want to know how to display the progress about uploading files

Tags: javascript, servlets, sftp, jsch

my web page have a button to select the files,when the  button clicked,it will send files data to webserver,then webserver will build a SFTP service which is built from JSCH,then the files will be sent to remote server.now I want to know how to develop the progress bar.I have already developed the progress bar when files send to web server.I try to develop the progress bar when files send to remote server but i failed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuSDV.png)

picture one is the process which sends files to webserver.
picture two is the process which sends files to remote server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20bz1.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Post it as a text.

Comment: sorry,first use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
// here is code which sends files to webserver. 
$(function() {

    $('#inputButton').on('click', function() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var files_upload_num = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;
        if(files_upload_num == 0)
        {
            alert('请选择文件，完成上传!');
            return;
        }
        for(let i=0;i<files_upload_num;i++)
            fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[i]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=path%>/FileCl?method=submitFile',
            type: 'post',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            xhr: function() {
                var newxhr;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    newxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    newxhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                newxhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    var percent = ( (e.loaded / e.total).toFixed(2) ) * 100 + '%'
                    $('#progressBar').css('width', percent)
                    document.getElementById('progressBar').innerHTML = percent;
                }
                newxhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
                newxhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
                newxhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
                return newxhr
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
    })
})
```

//here is code which sends files to remote server.

```
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        Session jSchSession = null;
        ChannelSftp chSftp = null;

        jSchSession = jSch.getSession(username, host, port);


        jSchSession.setPassword(password);


        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jSchSession.setConfig(config);


        jSchSession.setTimeout(1000*10);


        jSchSession.connect();


        chSftp = (ChannelSftp)jSchSession.openChannel("sftp");

        chSftp.connect();

        chSftp.setFilenameEncoding("UTF-8");



        sftpUtil sftpUtil = new sftpUtil(chSftp);


        for (FileItem item : fileItemList) {
            String filename = item.getName();
            if (filename == null || filename.trim().equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-","");
            id = id.substring(0,8);

            File saveFile = new File(path,id+filename);
            fileNameList.add(id+filename);
            sftpUtil.upload("/home/liuyb/uploads",filename,item.getInputStream(),new uploadFileProgressMonitor(item.getSize()));
        }
```